# 2023 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/election/1#questionnaire).**

---

Craft CMS Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election [next week, 2023-02-28](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/election/1). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here’s how it’ll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2023-02-28 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

  - How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
  - How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?
- The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

  - In your opinion, what do moderators do?
  - A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
  - In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching enough reputation to [access moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) or become a [trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user)?
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

  - We will post the final questionnaire on the [Election page](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/election/1). Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
  - This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Great, thanks for organizing this. I've posted my questions below, looking forward to seeing some quality nominations!

Comment: @LindseyD: Rather than copying the following comment below all three of your replies, I'll just ask here: Do you feel that the answer to your proposed questions will help the community judge whether a candidate would be a good moderator for the site? If so, how/why? (I ask because a user's experience level with the Craft CMS product and/or their participation in a Discord community doesn't inherently tell me anything about their participation on this site or understanding of how to use moderator tools here, for instance.)

Comment: Indeed, I do feel like all three questions would help identify a good moderator (from the perspective of the Craft community). **Familiarity with the product** shows that they truly understand the questions being posted, and **familiarity with the community** shows that they understand the best way to find relevant information and solutions.

Comment: With all due respect, "anyone" can learn how to use the SE moderator tools. You all have designed them to be relatively intuitive. :)

Answer (score 2):

How long have you been using Craft CMS?

Answer (score 1):

How frequently do you use Craft CMS? As a developer, or in some other role?

Answer (score 1):

Are you also active on the Craft CMS Discord channel?

Answer (score 1):

What are the most important qualities of an answer on the Craft CMS Stack Exchange, and are those qualities consistent among other product-centric communities?